# Python // Parse Json to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, json, parsing

I have some problems with parsing json in responce.
I want to load data into MySQL database.

json like this:

```
{
"data":
    [{"dimensions":
        [{"name":"2018-05-01"},
        {"name":"Переходы из поисковых систем","icon_id":"2","icon_type":"traffic-source","id":"organic"},
        {"name":"Смартфоны","id":"mobile"},
        {"name":"Google, результаты поиска","id":"google_search","favicon":"google.com"},
        {"iso_name":"RU MOW","id":"213","name":"Москва"},
        {"icon_id":"225","icon_type":"country","iso_name":"RU","id":"225","name":"Россия"},
        {"name":null,"url":null,"favicon":null}],
    "metrics":[13.0,38.0]}]
}
```

I want to get result like this:

```
MySQL header => ym:s:date  // ym:s:lastTrafficSource // ym:s:deviceCategory//ym:s:lastSearchEngine // ym:s:regionCity // ym:s:regionCountry // ym:s:lastSearchPhrase // ym:s:visits // ym:s:pageviews

insert rows => 2018-05-01 // Переходы из поисковых систем // Смартфоны // Google, результаты поиска // Москва // Россия // null // 13.0 // 38.0
```

Example of my function:

```
def get_json():
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    parse = json_data.get('data')
    for rows in parse:
        get_dimensions = rows.get('dimensions')
        get_metrics = rows.get('metrics')
        for names in get_dimensions:
            get_names = names.get('name')
            print(get_names)
```

Can't understand how to make list of dimensions and metrics
and load to MySQL

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Is the mysql table exist yet? If yes, you sould write how it looks like (DDL), if no, you can use tools which make it easier to insert, update to any sql. Use [sqlalchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) if you are not familier with sql enough.

Comment: Expect row in MySQL
2018-05-01 // Переходы из поисковых систем // Смартфоны // Google, результаты поиска // Москва // Россия // null // 13.0 // 38.0

Comment: That is only mysql version I think. I asked the table. What do you know about sql queries?

Comment: I use pymysql.
But I don't understand how to create list of values from this json
Because I can INSERT VALUES list[0], list[1], list[2]....

Comment: json1_data = json.loads(json1_str), after that, you have to specify the column order as expected in the insert or create a query with column names. If you don't provide a DDL ot the table, we cannot provide real example.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
def get_json():
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    json_data = json.loads(r.text)
    parse = json_data.get('data')
    for rows in parse:
        get_dimensions = rows.get('dimensions')

        date = get_dimensions[0].get('name')
        source = get_dimensions[1].get('name')
        device = get_dimensions[2].get('name')
        source1 = get_dimensions[3].get('name')
        city = get_dimensions[4].get('name')
        country = get_dimensions[5].get('name')
        search_phrase = get_dimensions[6].get('name')

        row = []
        row.append(date)
        row.append(source)
        row.append(device)
        row.append(source1)
        row.append(city)
        row.append(country)
        row.append(search_phrase)
```